# Adding a struct into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I'm having trouble adding a struct into a map. I don't really understand the error.

There are 2 errors:

1. I can't declare a map with 'struct' type
2. I can't use insert to 'insert' my struct into the map

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    typedef struct 
    {   
        std::string stringVar;
        unsigned unsignedVar;
        float floatVar;
    } MyTypeDefStruct;

    MyTypeDefStruct myTypeDefStruct;
    myTypeDefStruct.stringVar = "myStr";
    myTypeDefStruct.unsignedVar = 1000;
    myTypeDefStruct.floatVar = -10.0;

    float anotherFloat = -20.0;

    std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::pair<MyTypeDefStruct, float> (myTypeDefStruct, anotherFloat));                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:21:36: error: template argument for 'template<class _Tp> struct std::less' uses local type 'main()::MyTypeDefStruct'
 std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;
                                ^
test.cpp:21:36: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _Tp> struct std::less'
test.cpp:21:36: error: template argument 3 is invalid
test.cpp:21:36: error: template argument for 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair' uses local type 'const main()::MyTypeDefStruct'
test.cpp:21:36: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
test.cpp:21:36: error: template argument 4 is invalid
test.cpp:21:43: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
 std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;
                                       ^
test.cpp:23:11: error: request for member 'insert' in 'myMap', which is of non-class type 'int'
 myMap.insert(std::pair<MyTypeDefStruct, float> (myTypeDefStruct, anotherFloat));
       ^
test.cpp:23:50: error: template argument for 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair' uses local type 'main()::MyTypeDefStruct'
 myMap.insert(std::pair<MyTypeDefStruct, float> (myTypeDefStruct, anotherFloat));
                                              ^
test.cpp:23:50: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
```

Comment: A sorted map needs a less operator (`operator<`) to sort the elements. You have to provide such operator or you have to set a sort function.

Comment: @ThomasSablik You can put your answer into the answer section down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. The struct should defined outside of the function main, can't see a reason why you want to define it there in this case, and since it is local inside of main, you can't use it anywhere else!
2. You are using the C-style `typedef struct ... StructName` instead of simply using `struct MyStruct`.
3. Your struct doesn't implement the `operator<`, hence, since `std::map` is an **ordered** map, and it doesn't have anyway to compare two keys (here, the key is your struct), it doesn't able to insert any pair.
4. Your struct doesn't implement the `operator==` which is important to actually ***retrieving*** the value of a certain key... You should be able to check if the keys are similar.
5. Another small fix - using `std::make_pair` instead of its ctor.

Your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct MyStruct
{   
    std::string stringVar;
    unsigned unsignedVar;
    float floatVar;

    friend bool operator<(const MyStruct& l, const MyStruct& r)
    {
        return std::tie(l.stringVar, l.unsignedVar, l.floatVar)
             < std::tie(r.stringVar, r.unsignedVar, r.floatVar);
    }

    friend bool operator==(const MyStruct& l, const MyStruct& r)
    {
        return std::tie(l.stringVar, l.unsignedVar, l.floatVar)
             == std::tie(r.stringVar, r.unsignedVar, r.floatVar);
    }
};  

int main()
{
    MyStruct my_struct;
    my_struct.stringVar = "myStr";
    my_struct.unsignedVar = 1000;
    my_struct.floatVar = -10.0;

    float anotherFloat = -20.0;

    std::map<MyStruct, float> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(my_struct, anotherFloat));

    return 0;
}
```

How did I get to identifying the first problem? In the first error (always look at the **first** error, the others may be misleading!), it is written:

```
test.cpp:21:36: error: template argument for 'template<class _Tp> struct std::less' uses local type 'main()::MyTypeDefStruct'
 std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;
```

Notice that the template initialization here is using `main()::MyTypeDefStruct` and not `MyTypeDefStruct`!!! These types are ***different***, and the first is available only in the *scope* of `main()`!

The third point is because when you fix the first point, you will get:

```
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const MyStruct' and 'const MyStruct')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! Is there an std::tie alternative for c++98?

Comment: @wait_wut why are you using C++98 in 2020?

Comment: @bolov Unfortunately, it's a project constraint.

Comment: @wait_wut Just writing down `l.stringVar < r.stringVar || ...`. You can figure it out on your own! The `std::tie` is just simpler, it isn't a must!

Comment: @wait_wut Also, if it fixed your problem, you should accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that map requires a way to compare two `myTypeDefStruct`s.
You'll need to do is define `operator<` or `std::less` for your class, or pass a comparison functor to the map.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::map<T>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) uses a comparator to insert your elements but there is no one defined for your struct, hence try to use something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
struct MyTypeDefStruct
{
    std::string stringVar;
    unsigned unsignedVar;
    float floatVar;
} ;

bool operator<(const MyTypeDefStruct& lhs, const MyTypeDefStruct& rhs){
    return lhs.unsignedVar < rhs.unsignedVar;
}

int main()
{


    MyTypeDefStruct myTypeDefStruct;
    myTypeDefStruct.stringVar = "myStr";
    myTypeDefStruct.unsignedVar = 1000;
    myTypeDefStruct.floatVar = -10.0;

    float anotherFloat = -20.0;

    std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::pair<MyTypeDefStruct, float> (myTypeDefStruct, anotherFloat));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A sorted map needs a less operator (`operator<`) to sort the elements. You have to provide such operator or you have to set a sort function. One possible solution is to implement this operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


struct MyTypeDefStruct {   
    std::string stringVar;
    unsigned unsignedVar;
    float floatVar;
};

bool operator<(const MyTypeDefStruct &lhs, const MyTypeDefStruct &rhs) {
    if (lhs.stringVar < rhs.stringVar) return true;
    if (lhs.stringVar > rhs.stringVar) return false;
    if (lhs.unsignedVar < rhs.unsignedVar) return true;
    if (lhs.unsignedVar > rhs.unsignedVar) return false;
    if (lhs.floatVar < rhs.floatVar) return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {

    MyTypeDefStruct myTypeDefStruct;
    myTypeDefStruct.stringVar = "myStr";
    myTypeDefStruct.unsignedVar = 1000;
    myTypeDefStruct.floatVar = -10.0;

    float anotherFloat = -20.0;

    std::map<MyTypeDefStruct, float> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::pair<MyTypeDefStruct, float> (myTypeDefStruct, anotherFloat));                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    return 0;
}
```